Cant double-click run executable and jar fies
You can probably tell im really new to this but i cant run executable and and jar files by double clicking them like i can with deb files. I can run these files fine using their respective methods from terminal (chmod and java) but double clicking does nothing

What are the commands with which you can run these files? If we know them, we can figure out a way to run them with GUI

If possible, can you share these files?

The file irrc is the Minecraft forge installer and i open the terminal in the downloads folder i have it in and type "java -jar thenameofthefile"
